# Vuetify date picker: multiple event indicators

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm learning Vue and Vuetify right now. And I want to develop a Calendar tool combining Vuetify with Laravel.

With v-calendar it is possible to render multiple 'event-indicators'

[See example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar-docs/master/gitbook/images/README/welcome-1.png)

With Vuetify 'one' event indicator is possible [(example)](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#example-date-events), but I don't know how to manage to make it two or even three. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try making 2 events on the same day?

Comment: I did, doesn't work. Does only spit out one 'event-div'

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can, just pass an array for all the colors you want to assign on a particular date, using the allowed-dates prop. It has been included in the vuetify examples as well.

Refer: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-pickers-events

Answer (score 0):

Yeah had a play around with it but doesn't seem you can get it to display multiple events as it is :( You can submit it as a feature though [here](https://issues.vuetifyjs.com/) and they're usually quite quick to respond if it's possible or not.  Sorry I can't help any other way.